# How to remove all HTML tags with sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I found a really great [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/unix-sed-tutorial-replace-text-inside-a-file-using-substitute-command/) explaining some practical `sed` examples.

The last one (number 10) can be seen below:

```
$ sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
This <b> is </b> an <i>example</i>.
This  is  an example.
```

Can someone please help me through this one?

To summarize where I'm at:
1. I understand : `s/x/y/g` is a command telling sed to "globally subsitute the regex `x` with the regex `y`
2. It seems like the `-e` flag puts sed in some sort of "interactive mode", from the `man` page:

```
-e command
             Append the editing commands specified by the command argument to
             the list of commands.
```

This seems confusing to me because it doesn't seem like we're giving `sed` a "list of commands" it seems like we're giving it a "list of arguments" so I'm not to sure on that one.
3. I understand that the first and only `<` is nothing more than the single char regex `<`, and the last `>` is nothing more than the single char regex `>`
4. I understand that the `*` is telling sed to match 0 or more occurances of the pattern before it, which is in this case inside the brackets; however, this is where I'm really confused: can someone please unpack the `[^>]*` more for me?

so where I'm really confused on is:

- what's going on with `-e` in plain english?
- what's going on with `[^>]*`?

Thanks :)

Comment: After you have learned the `sed` syntax, understand that removing HTML using simple sed substitutions isn't going to be perfect, ever: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/308668. `sed` could be able to parse it using its other features, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence `s/<[^>]*>//g` is a *command* to the `sed` processing engine; it tells it to do a "Search and replace".  So `-e 's/..../g'` means "add this search and replace command to the execution of `sed`.

This may make more sense if we do multiple commands in one command:

```
sed -e '1d' -e '$d'
```

would add two commands to the `sed` processing; "delete first line" and "delete last line".

The `[^>]` is a regular expression that means "any character except for the `>`

So `[^>]*` means "zero or more of any character except for the `>`

And so `<[^>]*>` means a `<`, optionally followed by non-`>`, followed by `>`.

And then we put that into a "search and replace" command where this sequence is replaced by nothing, and *then* do it multiple times in the line (the final `g`).

This means that the string `hello <abc> there <def>` will first match `<abc>` (the `<`, then `abc` matches "zero or more non-`>`", then the `>`) and replace that with nothing, and then redo this for the `<def>`.  The result would be `hello  there`.

(Note the extra spaces, 'cos we're not removing them!)

Answer (score 4):

Limiting the scope to the two points:

- The `-e` tells `sed` that there is an editing command following
- The `[^>]*` is a pattern that matches zero-or-more characters that can be "anything" except the **`>`** character

and the editing command says

```
's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

change anything that matches **`<`**, followed by any number of characters up until the first **`>`** to **nothing**.  And do that as many times as there are matches.